# QuickConnect vs Phonegap

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, cordova, xui

What JavaScript Mobile development tool would you use based on momentum, existing documentation and functionality, and ability to get passed the App Stores strict policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Phonegap to be the easiest to use.  However Quickconnect seems to be more ambitious in terms of multi-platform support, the author tells me that Quickconnect has been used in many apps (but couldn't disclose which). Supposedly Phonegap apps were being rejected because those submitting were loading the entire apps off the web, however the framework does seem sluggish.  Apple has not replied to the Phonegap team about the app rejection.

If I had to make a choice it would be Phonegap at this stage, but unless you really want the app on multiple platforms I don't see why you wouldn't use the great tools provided by Apple for native development.

Comment: I am not sure I could catch up on objective C development.  The syntax is strange, there are files all over the place, and there is  memory maintenance stuff going on.  That said, I wish I had time develop a native app.

Answer (score 4):

Current PhoneGap release (0.8.0) released 2009-10-13 is tagged "Apple approved for App Store submissions".  [This blog post](http://nachbaur.com/blog/phonegap-officially-permitted-on-the-app-store) has more details.

Answer (score 2):

I used PhoneGap to port a JavaScript game and I loved it. Unfortunately, the game was too slow (Mobile Safari is slow when you make changes to the DOM, and I was moving divs around as sprites) and I switched to native.

But since some people started getting having their PhoneGap apps rejected, I have become shy of the project. I'd love to hear an official stance from Apple, but I don't know if it'll ever come.

Answer (score 1):

At this point you might also want to look at Titanium by Appcelerator.

The development process is pretty simple, and they support both the iPhone and Android platforms.